# Can we modify the previous row and use it in current row in a SQL query for a list?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, analytics, oracle12c

I've looked around and found a few posts with LAG() and running total type queries, but none seem to fit what I'm looking for.  Maybe i'm not using the correct terms in my search or maybe I might be over complicating the situation.  Hope someone could help me out.

But what I'm looking to do is to take the previous result and multiple it by the current row for a range of dates.  The starting is always some base number lets do 10 to keep it simple.  The values will be float, but i kept it to round numbers here to better explain my inquiry.

The first is showing the calculation part and the 2nd table below is showing what the result should look like in the end.

```
date     val1 calc_result
20120930 null 10
20121031    2 10*2=20
20121130    3 20*3=60
20121231    1 60*1=60
20130131    2 60*2=120
20130228    1 120*1=120
```

The query would return

```
20120930 10
20121031 20
20121130 60
20121231 60
20130131 120
20130228 120
```

I'm trying to see if this can be done in a query type solution or would a PL/SQL table/cursors need to be used?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?????  SO is not a free coding service.  You post your query.  If it doesn't get the right result, explain what's wrong, what's the expected output.  Then we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.date, t.val, 10 as calc_result
      from dates t
      where t.seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.date, t.val, cte.calc_result * t.val
      from cte join
           dates t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select cte.date, cte.calc_result
from cte
order by cte.date;
```

Comment: Ok I played around with this one and it seems to be working. I had to read up on what CTE was via this [link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_common_table_expression_cte.htm) I will continue to modify this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This is calculating a cumulative product. You can do it with some exponential arithmetic. Replace `10` in the query with the desired start value.

```
select date,val1
,case when row_number() over(order by date) = 1 then 10  --set start value for first row
 else 10*exp(sum(ln(val1)) over(order by date)) end as res 
from tbl
```

Comment: This is close but it appears the first row is being multipled as well and causing the rest of the numbers to be off. So the first row should always be 10 or set number, the 2nd row will be prev_row * curr_row which is 10*2. The sample you provided displays 10 but the 2nd row is not multiplied by 10 but by the product of that 10*curr_row.